# Get data from ICMP package

Tags: python, python-3.x, scapy, icmp

Could you tell me please, get more detailed information about the ICMP packet?
Right now I'm using some code construction:

```
import scapy.layers.inet
from scapy.all import *


def gettingDataFromICMPTraffic(pkt):
    if pkt.haslayer(scapy.layers.inet.ICMP):
        type_8 = pkt.getlayer(scapy.layers.inet.ICMP).type
        if type_8 == 8:
            print(pkt.getlayer(scapy.layers.inet.ICMP))


def main():
    pkts = rdpcap('icmp_yes.pcap')
    for pkt in pkts:
        gettingDataFromICMPTraffic(pkt)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I get some information in the form:

```
ICMP 192.168.34.163 > 192.168.34.118 echo-request 0 / Raw
ICMP 192.168.34.163 > 192.168.34.118 echo-request 0 / Raw
ICMP 192.168.34.163 > 192.168.34.136 echo-request 0 / Raw / Padding
ICMP 192.168.34.163 > 192.168.34.136 echo-request 0 / Raw / Padding
```

I would like to get more information regarding the `Sequence Number` parameters, as is done in `Wireshark`.

[image]

I looked in the [documentation](https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/scapy.layers.inet.html#scapy.layers.inet.ICMP) and didn't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's `seq` attribute among [ICMP fields](https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/scapy.layers.inet.html#scapy.layers.inet.ICMP):

```
def gettingDataFromICMPTraffic(pkt):
    if pkt.haslayer(scapy.layers.inet.ICMP):
        type_8 = pkt.getlayer(scapy.layers.inet.ICMP).type
        if type_8 == 8:
            icmp_layer = pkt.getlayer(scapy.layers.inet.ICMP)
            print(icmp_layer, f'; seq number: {icmp_layer.seq}')
```

---

Sample output:

```
ICMP 192.168.158.139 > 174.137.42.77 echo-request 0 / Raw ; seq number: 8448
ICMP 192.168.158.139 > 174.137.42.77 echo-request 0 / Raw ; seq number: 8704
ICMP 192.168.158.139 > 174.137.42.77 echo-request 0 / Raw ; seq number: 8960
ICMP 192.168.158.139 > 174.137.42.77 echo-request 0 / Raw ; seq number: 9216
```

Comment: I understand that this is a different question, but maybe you can tell me how I can get information from the `Date` field. Thank you very much

Comment: @AlexRebell, where did you see the field `Date`?

Comment: sorry, I asked the wrong question. I meant the `Data` field as specified in the `Wireshark` program. I have changed the picture to my question above.